# A question regarding bhakti?

Tags: vishnu, bhagavata-purana, bhakti

In Bhagavatam 8.16.21 Kashyapa muni tells Aditi that "Amogham bhagavat bhakti na itareti iti matir mama"
Devotion to Supreme Lord is infallible not others,this is my opinion..
Does it mean we cannot pray to other Devtas and Gurus for our problems?
We find in Ramayana Lord Himself prays to Durga Devi and Lord Siva etc..
Also various methods of worship of devatas are given in Scriptures for well being of humans are they useless then?
Is this shloka an extrapolation?
What is your opinion?

Comment: You are citing a *purana* literally! That means smritis (incl. puranas) were written from memory and compiled from various sources. They have inconsistencies and conflict over various areas within. Unless a shruti (that is transmitted word-by-word), they shouldn't be taken too literally over certain words, specially sectrian ones.